# HTML & Bootstrap 5 - Center content of a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center the content of a column using Bootstrap. This is my current code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- CODE -->
    
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <!-- LEFT -->
           <div class="col-md-6 p-md-5 p-4" style="background-color: lime;">
             <div> <!-- THIS SHOULD BE IN THE CENTER -->
               <h1>Welcome</h1>
               <h2>to my web!</h2>
             </div>
             
             <div> <!-- THIS SHOULD BE IN THE BOTTOM -->
               <p>Icons</p>
             </div>
           </div>
           

           <!-- RIGHT -->
           <div class="col-6 d-md-block d-none" style="background-color: red"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using `d-flex justify-content-center`, as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- CODE -->
    
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <!-- LEFT -->
           <div class="col-md-6 p-md-5 p-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="background-color: lime;">
             <div> <!-- THIS SHOULD BE IN THE CENTER -->
               <h1>Welcome</h1>
               <h2>to my web!</h2>
             </div>
             
             <div> <!-- THIS SHOULD BE IN THE BOTTOM -->
               <p>Icons</p>
             </div>
           </div>
           

           <!-- RIGHT -->
           <div class="col-6 d-md-block d-none" style="background-color: red"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this is not working...

How can I do to put the elements correctly inside the column?

Answer (score 1):

You can add “ align-items-center” to the class, if that still doesn’t work, make sure you’re not adding different margins to left and right of the section, but justify-content-center and align-items-center will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding `d-flex flex-column h-100` to the child, with an `align-items-center` solves the scenario.